# Set a variable with Radio Buttons

Tags: java, android

I'm super new to programming and try to create a small Android app.
I want to set the variable "stufe" to 1 or 2 depending on the pressed Radio button.
But it always remains 0.
This is my code...i hope you can help me:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//Radio Button
private int stufe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(stufe));
}

public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            RadioButton onebutton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
            RadioButton twobutton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
            if (onebutton.isChecked()){
                stufe = 1;
                onebutton.setChecked(true);
                twobutton.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                stufe = 2;
                onebutton.setChecked(false);
                twobutton.setChecked(true);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you observing the values of `stufe`? Only via textView2 or have you done some debugging?

Comment: I only did it via textView2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to setText after you have changed the `stufe` value.

**Try this:**

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
                    switch (checkedId){
                        case R.id.radio_one:
                            stufe = 1;
                            break;
                        case R.id.radio_two:
                            stufe = 2;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(stufe));
            }
        });
```

Comment: The variable is now set within the method onCheckecChanged.....is there any whay to set it globally so i can use it afterwards everywhere?

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want to set globally?

Comment: inside the method onCHeckedChanged everything works, but outside (e.g somewhere in the onCreate method the variable seem to be set back to zero...